# Using two different versions of python but sqlmap needs 2.7

Tags: python, path, sqlmap

I've recently started using sqlmap and found out it needs python2.7. I installed 2.7 and added it to my `PATH` along with 3.4. My current path looks like this:

```
c:\Other-Programs\;c:\Python27;c:\Python34
```

So When I try to run sqlmap i follow these steps:

```
1. Open up cmd as admin
2. cd c\:sqlmap
3. python sqlmap.py
```

At this point, sqlmap informs me that Python 3.4 is incompatible.
I tried just doing:

```
3. python27 sqlmap.py
```

That returns an error stating that it's not a command.

Basically I want to know how I can specify the version of Python I want to use when running a command for sqlmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using full path of python exe `C:\Python27\python.exe sqlmap.py`.

Answer (score 1):

While you normally would try to do something clever with PATH definition here, a very simple solution would be to do something like this (unproven because I'm not on Windows but)

C:\Python2.7\bin\python.exe your_script_for2.7.py (make sure you are pointing to the right path of python.exe) and for 3.x

C:\Python3.x\bin\python.exe your_script_for3.x.py

What you're experiencing is probably the latest python installed, replaced the global python executable. You should be able to use python2.7 or python3.x as well though.

Answer (score 0):

Me too had similar problem in **windows**, i was having python 3.5(and its path set in environment variables), so i installed python 2.7 from their site.then i did the following to start sqlmap

1) Got inside the folder of python 27 in cmd

2) executed the following command

```
python.exe "path to sqlmap-dev\sqlmap.py"
```